# non-trivial convergent sequence

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

I have reached a deadlock to find a  example to show that a compact Hausdorff space does not need to have a  no non-trivial convergent sequence.(except $\beta\omega$)

> **can you give me a example of a compact Hausdorff space with no non-trivial convergent sequence?**

Comment: In a comment on the previous question I stated that every compact $F$-space is an example of a compact Hausdorff space with no non-trivial convergent sequence. Please do not repeat a question that has been answered already.

Comment: A one-point space?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only known example is $\beta\omega$ (and spaces that contain copies of $\beta\omega$), I sort of recall (but don't take my word on that) that the question of whether there exists other example is still open.

Comment: There are consistent examples of infinite compact spaces which contain no non-trivial convergent sequence and no copy of $\beta\omega$. It is still open whether there is an example in $ZFC$.

Comment: I see, so the point is getting the thingy in $\mathscr{ZFC}$, or proving that it consistently doesn't exist. Do you have any idea in which models do those examples live?

Comment: The classic examples are due to Fedorchuk; one is constructed under $\diamondsuit$, another under $CH$ and a third one under $\mathfrak{s}=\aleph_1 + 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$. For more details, search for "Efimov's problem".